# asp.net mvc3 razor custom button helper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I've created a custom button helper. I pass text, url, css attributes, and everything works perfectly fine. The only thing that I would like to improve is to incorporate a ActionLink functionality into that button. For example I would like to pass the action name and the controller name and that would return the link to that page (just like ActionLink)

Does anyone worked on that same issue and is willing to share, or at least give me hint on how to do it? thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Url.Action method for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the methods in the `Url` object to get URLs for actions.

If you don't have a `Url` object, you can write `new UrlHelper(ViewContext.RequestContext)`.

Comment: Yeah I just got it to work. I used @Url.Action and passed as string to the c# class. Works great. Thank you!